# Showing a bound on the $L_2$ error in the N-sparse approximation of a vector

Tags: machine-learning, svm, unsupervised-learning, sparse

This is a supposedly 'trivial bound' from Donoho's Compressed Sensing paper - trying to figure out where it comes from.

Assume that $\theta$ is a vector that obeys the following constraint for some $0<p<2$ and for some $R > 0$

$||\theta||_p = \left( \sum_i |\theta_i|^p \right)^{1/p} \leq R$

If $\theta_N$ denotes the vector $\theta$ with everything except $N$ largest coefficients set to $0$ then we have

$$ || \theta - \theta_N ||_2 \leq C_{2,p} \cdot ||\theta||_p \cdot (N+1)^{1/2 - 1/p} $$

for $N=0,1,2,...$ and constant $C_{2,p}$ depending only on $p \in (0,2)$.

Comment: So what is the question? The width of the bound? Where the expression comes from?

Comment: Is this supposed to be true for any $p \in (0, 2)$, and can $\theta$ have any dimension?

Comment: Please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find information on how to do 
this in the **My Account** section of our [help]), then you will be able to 
edit & comment on your own question.

Comment: @Andy just trying to figure out where it comes from.

Comment: @dsaxton I think so yes, please check my new edit though that adds a missing constraint on $\theta$